# busboy is not defined connect-busboy with expres

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, busboy

I am working with expressjs 4.12.3, and trying to connect to connect-busboy, but on request I am not able to get req.busboy object, it says "undefined" my simple code is as follows :

```js
var express=require('express');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var app=express();
app.use(busboy());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
     // console.log(fieldname, val);
     req.body[fieldname] = val;
   });

   req.busboy.on('finish', function(){
     next();
   });
 });
 
 app.listen(5555);
```

I have initialize busboy module, assigned it to the app, also sending 
content-length: "5276"
content-type:'application/x-www-formurlencoded' as headers.

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: [The request method is also not GET or HEAD](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy#typeerror-cannot-call-method-on-of-undefined)?

Comment: request method is 'POST'

Comment: I used [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), worked seamlessly, without listening to any events

Comment: I will give it a try with multer, even this code should work, to be sure I just checked the req.method in node-inspector, it says "POST" now I am totally clueless why it is behaving so.

Comment: Used multer library which works like a charm, but I still would like to know what is wrong with above code, any suggestions?

Comment: Dunno, probably you'd need look into the source code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting up event handlers, but you're not actually piping the request *to* busboy so it can parse the request. Add `req.pipe(req.busboy);` after your busboy event handlers and it should work fine.

**EDIT:** I slightly misread your question. If `req.busboy` is `undefined` that means the `Content-Type` is wrong. If your `Content-Type` *really is* `application/x-www-formurlencoded`, then that is wrong. It *should* be: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I tried with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" issue still persist, with respect to events, I thought "app.use(busboy())" takes care of that?